# Why don't calls to drupal_set_message() show up after a drupal_goto()?

Tags: 7, forms

My question is similar to [How to  redirect the user to a  page and show a message on the admin overlay (using drupal_set_message and drupal_goto)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/how-to-redirect-the-user-to-a-page-and-show-a-message-on-the-admin-overlay-us), but I'm not doing an overlay -- it's just a straight page.  This issue has been talked around a bit on this site, but I've never seen a real resolution of it.

My situation is:

- The user submits a form, through the usual method.
- The form has a _submit() handler, which runs: it does some stuff,
  sets a drupal_set_message(), and then redirects somewhere via
  drupal_goto().
- The user properly ends up on the intended page, but the message is
  nowhere to be seen.

Any clues on this?  I really can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I tried calling `drupal_goto()` right after `drupal_set_message()` in a test form, but the message was shown in the page where I was redirected. `drupal_goto()` should not be used in a form submission handler, but that is not what causes the message not to appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that `drupal_goto()` in a form submit handler is bad. The reason is that `drupal_goto()` shuts down Drupal right after sending the location header, so the rest of your site functionality will not work.

To make a redirect, pass `$form_state` as reference in your submission handler (`FORM_ID_submit($form, &$form_state)`), and then set `$form_state['redirect']` to where you want to send the user, for example with  `$form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add';`.

Comment: Ah, I knew that... :)  Once, anyway.  So, (a) thanks!, but (b) although the redirection is happening correctly, the message is still not appearing.  Any further thoughts? :)

Comment: Can you show us your code? I usually drupal_set_message() just above setting the $form_state['redirect'] and it works.

Answer (score 5):

I tried in my test site, and the message appears, even using `drupal_goto()`. I used the following code.

```
function code_testing_date_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['expire'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#title' => t('Expire Date'),
    '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    '#date_format' => 'Y-H:s',
    '#date_year_range' => '0:+20',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['weight'] = array(
    '#type' => 'weight',
    '#title' => t('Weight'),
    '#description' => t('Optional. In the menu, the heavier items will sink and the lighter items will be positioned nearer the top.'),
    '#default_value' => 5,
    '#delta' => 10,
    '#access' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function code_testing_date_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('You have been redirected.');
  drupal_goto('user');
}
```

[image: screenshot]

What could cause the issue you are seeing could be:

- There is code that clears the content of `$_SESSION['messages']`, used to contain the messages set with `drupal_set_message()`.
- There is code that invalidate the current session. In this case, the logged-in user should be logged out.
- You are rendering the form in a template file.
- The template file for the page to which the users are redirected doesn't have code to handle the `$messages` variable. The default node.tpl.php file contains the following code; if the template doesn't print `$messages`, the messages set with `drupal_set_message()` will be not seen.

  ```
  <?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
    <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $messages; ?>
  <div id="main-wrapper"><div id="main" class="clearfix">
  ```

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not rendering the form in a template file, but the page that I'm redirecting to is handled by a template file -- I'm redirecting to 'user/123', which is rendered by page--user.tpl.php.  I put some watchdog statements in the template file, and I'm seeing that it gets called twice.  The first time, $messages has a value that is presumably displayed, but (of course, I guess) the second time the value has gone away.  Any thoughts on where the second invocation is coming from, and how to stop it from happening?

Comment: FWIW, other watchdog statements indicate that the _form_submit() handler is only being called once.

Comment: One more update before giving up for the night: More watchdog statements show that the template's "print render($page['content'])" line, which is rendering the user page, causes the page--user.tpl template to be invoked for a second time. It appears that it's the results of this second invocation that actually shows up in the browser, with $messages having been cleared by the first invocation.  Sigh.

Comment: FinalFinal update (yes, I lied.)  If I redirect to some page other than user/123 -- the template page -- the messages come up correctly.

Comment: There is code in the user.tpl template file to print $messages; the problem seems to be in the double invocation of the template.

Comment: Closing out: Thanks to all for the help. The point about $form_state['redirect'] was certainly the main thing; there's still something else going on, but I'll deal with that, one way or another.  Your time/efforts were much appreciated!

Comment: FinalFinal closing out: I tracked down the "something else going on", and now understand what was happening -- it was indeed on my end.