# How do I display a message after redirecting users from the logout page?

Tags: 7, redirection, status-messages

I'd like to show a message via `drupal_set_message()` after redirecting users from user/logout?destination=user.

I tested this code but it doesn't work.

```
if ($find) { 
  drupal_set_message(t('This entry is ignored.'), 'error');

  $form_state['redirect'] = array(
    'user/logout',
    array('query' => array('destination' => 'user')),
  );

  drupal_redirect_form($form_state);
}
```

How do I display a message after redirecting user from the logout page?

Comment: I find the soluce :  [how-to-redirect-the-user-to-a-page-and-show-a-message-on-the-admin-overlay-us](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/how-to-redirect-the-user-to-a-page-and-show-a-message-on-the-admin-overlay-us)

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code, it appears to me that you want to redirect `/user/logout` to `/user`.

If that's what you actually want, then you could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this, using an approach that is similar to my answer to the question "[How to create a redirect to point to the user's id?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166803/how-to-create-a-redirect-to-point-to-the-users-id-in-drupal-7)", in which you use values for `the_old_path` and `the_new_path` that fit your needs here, i.e.:

1. Change all occurences of `the_old_path` to `user/logout`.
2. Change all occurences of `the_new_path` to `user`.
3. Adapt the message being displayed to fit your needs, so that the user will also receive an informational message, e.g. similar to something like this one:

   > *The path `/user/logout` has been redirected automatically to path `/user`.*

   If you don't want such message to appear, then just delete the line containing `drupal_message` in the rule.

## Use the value of the [destination] variable in the redirect

In case you want to make the value  (`user` in this case) of the URL argument (`destination` in this case) available as new variable to Rules, you can use the [Rules URL Argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument) module. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides two rules conditions based on URL arguments:
>
> - check if a URL argument is present.
> - compare the value of an URL argument.
>
> It also provides an action that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.

The newly provided Rules actions and conditions can be found under the "URL Argument" conditions and actions groups in the rule configuration interface.

For an example of how to use it, refer to [Comment # 3 in issue # 1686360](https://www.drupal.org/node/1686360#comment-6306112) which is about "*Pass an amount to the url, ie; site/content/node-title?amount=10 or /node-title?=amount:10*". Here is the relevant part of it:

> - add a "Check if URL argument exist" condition to your rule and set the "ARGUMENT" value to "amount".
> - add "Provide URL argument value" action to the rule and set "URL ARGUMENT NAME" value to "amount" and in the "Provided variables" section "ARGUMENT FROM URL - Variable name" to e.g. "`amount_from_url`".
>
> You will now be able to use the amount value as a variable "`amount-from-url`" for other actions in this rule.

**PS**: If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework).

Comment: I'm working on Drupal 7.37.
When I just redirects to `user/logout` I am automatically redirected to  `node`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Are you saying something like 'I must use **user/logout?destination=user** instead of just **user/logout** as the path to be redirected'? If so, I'll adapt my answer accordingly (that's possible too).

Comment: Hello, When I made ​​a redirection to `user/logout` page , I log out and automatically redirect to the page `node`

Comment: Thanks for your new comment. But it's about the same as your prior comment, and I still don't understand it completely. Try to correct my "guess" in my prior comment. I THINK you ask something like  'I must use user/logout?destination=user instead of just user/logout as the path to be redirected'? Can you CORRECT whatever is needed in what I think your question is? FYI: I extended my answer a bit.

Comment: There is no module for drupal 8 but I can pass argument. However, I don't want to display message again when user refresh the page. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: @cissharp : I'm not aware of how to do so in D8. Maybe you should post a NEW question about that? If you want, with a link to this question?